# Reverse List in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview

I am new to flutter. I am trying to reverse the list that I send to Listview.builder.

Here is the List:

```
final List<Transaction> _userTransactions = [
     Transaction(
       id: 't1',
       title: 'Shoes',
       amount: 2500,
       date: DateTime.now(),
     ),
     Transaction(
       id: 't2',
       title: 'Food',
       amount: 500,
       date: DateTime.now(),
     ),
  ];
```

Transaction is a class with mentioned properties. I want to reverse the list before sending it to ListView.builder. Thanks in advance.

P.S. User inputs new transaction, I want to sort the transactions with latest one on top for that I want to reverse my list.

Comment: Have you tried `_userTransactions.reversed.toList()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.reversed` a method from the `List` object that returns an `Iterable`.

Just call `_userTransactions.reversed.toList()` before sending it or assign it to a new variable like:

```
final reversedList = List.from(_userTransactions.reversed);
```

Comment: Note also that there is a property in listview called `reverse` which does the same thing